# C# - How to close application process from task manager using a button code?

Tags: c#, exit

In my current C# project, when I use the release executable version, when I use the close button I made

```
Application.Exit();
```

it doesn't kill the process in the task manager, and I'd like it to close there too. How could I go about to do that?

Comment: The problem is most likely you have threads running in the background so the program is still running even though the window is closed. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050341/application-is-still-running-in-memory-after-application-exit-is-called).

Comment: Please give a [mcve] illustrating the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can try 
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();

some threads you created in your program will try abort and you will lose data or something because the logic not end correctly.

ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_methods(v=vs.110).aspx